# How to update the result on right side based on user input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

    class Arithmetic extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)  
            this.state = {
               num1: 10,
               num2: 5,
            }
        }
        //the user input
        updateNum1(event) {
          this.setState({
           num1: event.target.value
            
           });
            
          }
        updateNum2(event){
            this.setState({
                num2: event.target.value
              
            });
          }
        render() {
           
      //calculation of values
            var sub=()=>{  
              const {num1, num2} = this.state;
              var subtraction = num1 - num2;
              document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = subtraction;
           
           }
    
           var mul=()=>{  
             const {num1, num2} = this.state;
             var multiplication = num1 * num2;
             document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= multiplication;
           
           }
        return (
                 <div className="container">
                   <div className="row">
                     <div className="col-md-8 calc_container">
                       
                        <div className="emi_input_value"> 
                          <div className="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light active switch" value="sub" 
                               name="invest_type" onClick={sub} checked>
                               Sub                         </button>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-light switch" value="mul" 
                               name="invest_type" onClick={mul}>
                               Mul
                             </button>
                          </div>
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <label class="label_name">Num1</label>  
                              <div className="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light active" value={10}  
                                onClick={this.updateNum1.bind(this)} checked>
                               10
                               </button>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" value={15}  onClick= 
                               {this.updateNum1.bind(this)} >
                               15
                               </button>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" value={20}  onClick= 
                               {this.updateNum1.bind(this)} >
                               20
                               </button>
                               <input type="textbox" className="form-control" placeholder="Custom" 
                               onChange={this.updateNum1.bind(this)} />
                           
                         </div>
       
                         <div className="form-group">
                           <label class="label_name">Num2</label>  <br></br>
                              <div className="btn-group">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-light active" value={5}  onClick= 
                                   {this.updateNum2.bind(this)} checked>
                                   5
                                 </button>
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-light " value={10}  onClick= 
                                   {this.updateNum2.bind(this)} >
                                   10
                                 </button>
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-light " value={15}  onClick= 
                                   {this.updateNum2.bind(this)} >
                                   15
                                 </button>
                                
                                 <input type="textbox" className="form-control" placeholder="Custom" 
                                  onChange={this.updateNum2.bind(this)} />
                               
                            </div>
                       </div>
                     </div> 
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="emi_output">
                     
                     <div class="calculated_output">
                       <h5>RESULT</h5>
                         
                         <div class="output_ph">
                           <label class="output_label">will grow to</label>
                           <label id="output" class="output_value"></label>
                         </div>
                        
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>    
               </div>
             </div> 
             
           
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Arithmetic
```

How to display the result for default value without clicking the button.How to change the result of sub and multiplication value on the user input based on button.
The value of the button is not going inside the sub and mul funtion without clicking button.I want to display the default value of the sub when the page is refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `value`  state inside input i.e

```
<input
                      type="textbox"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Custom"
                      value={this.state.num2}
                      onChange={this.updateNum2.bind(this)}
                    />
<input
                    type="textbox"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Custom"
                    value={this.state.num1}
                    onChange={this.updateNum1.bind(this)}
                  />
```

Here is full code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Arithmetic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      num1: 10,
      num2: 5,
      action: "sub",
      value: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.action === "sub") {
      this.updateSub();
    } else {
      this.updateMul();
    }
  }
  //the user input
  updateNum1(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        num1: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.action === "sub") {
          this.updateSub();
        } else {
          this.updateMul();
        }
      }
    );
  }
  updateNum2(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        num2: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.action === "sub") {
          this.updateSub();
        } else {
          this.updateMul();
        }
      }
    );
  }
  updateAction = (action) => {
    this.setState({ action }, () => {
      if (action === "sub") {
        this.updateSub();
      } else {
        this.updateMul();
      }
    });
  };
  updateSub = () => {
    const { num1, num2 } = this.state;
    var subtraction = num1 - num2;
    this.setState({ value: subtraction });
    // return subtraction;
  };

  updateMul = () => {
    const { num1, num2 } = this.state;
    var multiplication = num1 * num2;
    console.log("multiplication", multiplication);
    // return multiplication;
    this.setState({ value: multiplication });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8 calc_container">
            <div className="emi_input_value">
              <div className="btn-group">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-light active switch"
                  value="sub"
                  name="invest_type"
                  onClick={() => this.updateAction("sub")}
                  checked
                >
                  Sub{" "}
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-light switch"
                  value="mul"
                  name="invest_type"
                  onClick={() => this.updateAction("multi")}
                >
                  Mul
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label class="label_name">Num1</label>
                <div className="btn-group">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-light active"
                    value={10}
                    onClick={this.updateNum1.bind(this)}
                    checked
                  >
                    10
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-light"
                    value={15}
                    onClick={this.updateNum1.bind(this)}
                  >
                    15
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-light"
                    value={20}
                    onClick={this.updateNum1.bind(this)}
                  >
                    20
                  </button>
                  <input
                    type="textbox"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Custom"
                    value={this.state.num1}
                    onChange={this.updateNum1.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label class="label_name">Num2</label> <br></br>
                  <div className="btn-group">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-light active"
                      value={5}
                      onClick={this.updateNum2.bind(this)}
                      checked
                    >
                      5
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-light "
                      value={10}
                      onClick={this.updateNum2.bind(this)}
                    >
                      10
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-light "
                      value={15}
                      onClick={this.updateNum2.bind(this)}
                    >
                      15
                    </button>

                    <input
                      type="textbox"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Custom"
                      value={this.state.num2}
                      onChange={this.updateNum2.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="emi_output">
              <div class="calculated_output">
                <h5>RESULT</h5>

                <div class="output_ph">
                  <label class="output_label">will grow to</label>
                  <label id="output" class="output_value">
                    {" "}
                    {this.state.value}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Arithmetic />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-butterfly-t802s?file=/src/App.js:0-5662

Comment: In this method I need to click(sub or mul) each time when I have to calculate.If I click any button(i.e sub or mul) it has to show the result on right side by default(Automatically).

Comment: right side mean? You want to show along with button?

Comment: It means https://codesandbox.io/s/async-butterfly-t802s?file=/src/styles.css in this your displaying the result..It has to change by deafult.

Comment: Once the sub button is selected it has to display the any number of user input result at a time.We don't want to click the button again and again.

Comment: How to display the active button(10-5) result when the page is refresh?

Comment: Cool make sure if its works for you mark this answer accepted and upvoted. if anyone stuck on same problem. Then this problem will popup(stackoverflow algorithm )